# AnkhSVN 2.5.12233 and visual studio 2010 solution update do not works

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

today i have updated our AnkhSVN client to new version 2.5.12233.
After this, when i update a solution i can't see changes until i restart visual studio 2010.

So, commit works fine, but the update does not refresh file (.cs, aspx, ecc) in solution.

Is this a new bug?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report that belongs on the product's support site.

Comment: It's a bug.  http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=753   Fixed in version 2.5.12269.474